# routing in codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter, routes

The page is displaying correctly but when i click for second page in pagination its showing page not found.when i had given route like this the problem take place..this is the route i had given..

```
$route['mens']='hardpolo_control/men_image';
$route['mens/(:any)']='hardpolo_control/men_image/$1';
```

this is pagination url

```
public function men_image($category_name=null)    
{   
    $category_id =$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_id($category_name);     
    $data['active_mn']=$category_id;
    $data['mendropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=8);
    $data['kidsdropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=9);
    $data['accessoriesdropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=21);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'mens/'.$category_name;
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Hardpolo_model->count_category_images($category_id);
    $data['men_category_galery']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_images($category_id,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->library('pagination',$config);
    $data['page_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('men_image',$data);
}
```

Comment: check this for pagination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912816/codeigniter-active-records-query-taking-too-much-time-to-load-data-from-database/36914711#36914711

Comment: also change this  $route['mens/(:any)'] to $route['mens/(:num)']

Comment: my pagination is working properly before its get routed...after giving route it comes like this

Comment: if i given the base_url like this, its working...$config['base_url'] = base_url().'hardpolo_control/men_image/'.$category_name;

Comment: yeah this is your route issue your are using /(:any) this is not correct for any you need to use /(.*) or pass in uri number like example/1 then use /(:num)

Comment: can you show me error

Comment: when i go for this url http://localhost/hardpolo/mens/T-shirts/3 its showing The page you requested was not found.

Comment: when i use num the first page itself is not getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111407/discussion-between-yaseen-and-mohammed).

Comment: yes you passing the wrong uri segment in route you show's `mens/your_uri_segment` and you passing this `mens/T-shirts/your_uri_segment`

Comment: Try with `$config['uri_segment'] = ! $this->uri_segment(3) ? 2 : 3`.

Comment: i had tried but didnt work