# Codeigniter Pagination using datamodel

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter pagination i'm using datamodel. I have 5020 records. When i open the page all the records loaded then only pagination happened. So it's take long time to loading. I need when i open the page directly shown in pagination. I tried in lot of methods no one can suitable for me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try pagination for pagination [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912816/codeigniter-active-records-query-taking-too-much-time-to-load-data-from-database/36914711#36914711).

Answer (score 0):

```
        You need to load pagination library :-



$this->load->library('pagination'); 

        Than you need to set the values according to your choice



$config['per_page']= 10;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('on which page you want to put the pagination').'/'; 
                $this->data['per_page_display'] = $config['per_page'];
                $config['total_rows'] = count( 'Get total records from your model');

                $this->data['totalcount'] = $config['total_rows'];


            $this->pagination->initialize($config);


            $this->data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


            $this->data['per_page'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
            $this->data['page'] = $offset;


        Than you can use your pagination on your view
```