# How to give specific url in pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to give specific url to  $config['base_url'] = ""; in pagination.
The url is http://localhost/ci/index.php/listing.
The flow of the my project is like this
    |-> admin_login (user login here)
      |-> list_menu (after login, select link for listing)
         |-> listing (here i want to show my pagination)

My base url is set to: http://localhost/ci
and routes pagwe set to: admin_login page.

so please help me to solve this. I am new to codeigniter.

my controller file
**listing.php**

```
 public function index()
 {
    // Pagination start here //
    //pagination settings
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('listing/index');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('student_info');
    $config['per_page'] = "5";
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
```

Comment: Just a note if your using ci3 versions do not leave base url blank not recommend these days.

Comment: for pagination check this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912816/codeigniter-active-records-query-taking-too-much-time-to-load-data-from-database/36914711#36914711)

Comment: check this url http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2014/04/pagination-with-codeigniter.html